# T-SQL query with variable declarations in Excel VBA Code fail

Tags: sql, t-sql, vba, excel

I got a problem with running SQL query with "declare" and "set" functions in VBA.

```
Sheets("Arkusz1").Select
connstring = _
"ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=my_database_server;UID=user;PWD=password;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=some_id;DATABASE=mydatabase"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Worksheets("Arkusz1").Range("A1"), Sql:=Array( _
"declare @dzisiaj date" & Chr(13), _
"set @dzisiaj = getdate()" & Chr(13), _
"select @dzisiaj as dzisiaj"))

    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With
```

In SQL Server 2012 that code works fine, but... when I embed it into it gives me a run-time error '1004'. Also VBA code works on other queries works well.

My full SQL query has about 90 lines with 2 variable declarations (one declaration is a value from another 30 line SQL query), so it's mandatory to include variable declarations :)

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The key is to use ADODB connection to import data via SQL Query. Also necessary is to check Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.0 library in Tools->References in Visual Basic Editor (Shortcut: Alt+F11 in Excel).

So, there is an example of my VBA code:

```
    Sub sql_query_import()

    ' Declarations
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Server connection settings
    Server_Name = "192.168.1.106\my_database" ' IP of server name
    Database_Name = "mydatabase" ' Database name
    User_ID = "myusername" ' User name
    Password = "mypassword" ' User password

    ' SQL Query
    SQLStr = "SET NOCOUNT ON " & Chr(13) ' it's mandatory if you don't want to get error 3704
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "declare @dzisiaj date " & Chr(13)
    SQLStr = SQLStr & "set @dzisiaj = getdate() " & Chr(13)
SQLStr = SQLStr & "select @dzisiaj as 'today'

    ' Connect to database
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    ' Start connection
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    ' Load data
    With rs
        For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
            Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name ' Include column name if not - delete it
        Next i
    End With
    Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs ' Start loading data to Cell A2


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Using in SQL Query "SET NOCOUNT ON" is necessary if you don't want to get error 3704.
Also, using

```
SQLStr = "SET NOCOUNT ON " & Chr(13) ' it's mandatory if you don't want to get error 3704
SQLStr = SQLStr & "declare @dzisiaj date " & Chr(13)
```

is more efficient way to include multi-line SQL Queries :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to vb and vba and learning myself, but I know you can declare and write to variables in VB.net which can then feed into an embedded SQL script. I would think you can do the same thing in vba. Here's what I suggest.

1. Declare a vb string like SQL_Var_1
2. Insert the 30-line SQL query as a separate query before the main query.
3. Write the result of the 30-line query to the vb string SQL_Var_1.
4. Remove the declarations from the Main SQL query but leaving the references to those variables.
5. Reference SQL_Var_1 as an input parameter in the embedded main query using the exact same name you used in the main query (i.e., @dzisiaj), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904500/vb-net-sql-error-must-declare-the-scalar-variable).

If you follow these steps for both SQL variables, you should be able to achieve the same result as if you were using the declared SQL variables.