# Trouble with syntax in VBA for SQL query

Tags: sql, vba

I've got the below VBA that I am trying to use to run an SQL query (that works fine in SSMS).

I am not very good at using VBA and am having trouble getting the correct syntax for the SQL query. I'm currently stuck on `incorrect syntax near '+'`, but once this is works, I no doubt will get the same for others!

Can anybody help with this where I am going wrong, or can anyone point me to where I can learn about the correct syntax's required in VBA for SQL?

Thanks in advance!

```
    Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set recset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        
'set parameters
    ServerSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value            'choose the server the database is located
    
'insert server name and database name
    sConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
               "Password=ExcelRep0rt;" & _
               "User ID=ExcelReport;" & _
               "Data Source=" & ServerSource & ";" & _
               "Use Encryption for Data=False"
    
    Conn.Open sConnect

'SQL query
    SQLQry = " DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);" & _
                " SET @Sql =" & _
                " STUFF(" & _
                " (SELECT" & _
                " NCHAR (10) + N 'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +" & _
                " N 'SELECT" & _
                " + QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N' AS dbName," & _
                " c_broker COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _
                " det_costheader COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _
                " cuname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _
                " ch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _
                " CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ch_date_req, 103) AS [Flight_Date]," & _
                " IIF(OUT.outstanding > 0, ''Yes'', ''No'') AS [Anything_Outstanding?]," & _
                " sum(c_grossmargin) / 2 AS [Gross_Margin]" & _
                " FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM" & _
                " Left Join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT" & _
                " ON COM.det_costheader = OUT.project" & _
                " WHERE c_broker = ''HKGCGOJT''" & _
                " GROUP BY det_costheader, c_broker, cuname, ch_name, ch_date_req, outstanding'" & _
                " FROM sys.databases d" & _
                " where name like '%AccountsLive'" & _
                " FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)" & _
                " .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');" & _
                " exec( @Sql );"
    
'import table - choose range of where to put the table
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
        recset.Open SQLQry, Conn
        Range("B10").CopyFromRecordset recset
        recset.Close

'Import Headers
    'For i = 0 To recset.Fields.Count - 1
    '    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Offset(0, i) = recset.Fields(i).Name
    'Next i

    Conn.Close
    Set recset = Nothing
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424438/t-sql-query-with-variable-declarations-in-excel-vba-code-fail/20520187#20520187

Comment: Is `incorrect syntax near '+'` raised by VBA (i.e. when you compile this code) or is it raised  when you try and run the SQL? For any dynamically generated SQL, the first step is to print out the result and test it. When you say it "works fine in SSMS", is that you literally printing the value of `SQLQry` and running it in SSMS?

Comment: First thing I see when I search on `+` in your query is things like this: `NCHAR (10) + N 'UNION ALL'` It's hard to tell but I really don't think there should be a space between `N` and a string literal. Anyway.... print out `SQLQry` and run it in SSMS and I bet you get the same error

Comment: The other thingis that you are creating dynamic SQL in a VBA variable called `SQLQry` which in turn generates dynamics SQL into a SQL variable called `@SQL` then runs it. You should just generate the dynamic SQL directly in VBA. i.e. generate what goes into `@SQL` directly in VBA and not go through the middle man.... Or create a stored procedure to do it.

Comment: Is this code creating a dynamic crosstab? Because there are better, more reliable, less code intensive ways to put a dynamic crosstab in Excel, like a pivot table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you for your reply....the query is what I created in SSMS first. I have then just copied & pasted into VBA in the `SQLQry` section shown above (adding the " at the beginning and end and the & _ ) as I am using this query as a wider macro as am just (trying) to get the data into Excel first, then manipulating it in various ways in VBA as part of a wider project

Comment: OK. You need to print the value of `SQLQry`, paste it into SSMS and troubleshoot from there. Use this method.  https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-debug-print/

Comment: Perfect - thanks for the help! I will give it a try and come back to this once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

With great direction from @Nick.McDermaid, I followed the below steps from https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-debug-print/:

In VBA:
Ctrl+G - bring up the Immediate Window
Add `Debug.Print SQLQry`
Run the macro and copy & paste the SQL in the Immediate Window into SSMS (or whatever you're using)

Then can see where you are going wrong in your query.

Just for reference, below is the correct SQL for my particular issue.

`SQLQry = " DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);" & _ " SET @Sql =" & _ " STUFF(" & _ " (SELECT" & _ " NCHAR (10) + N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(10) +" & _ " N'SELECT" & _ " '+ QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') + N' AS dbName," & _ " c_broker COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _ " det_costheader COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _ " cuname COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _ " ch_name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS," & _ " CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ch_date_req, 103) AS [Flight_Date]," & _ " IIF(OUT.outstanding > 0, ''Yes'', ''No'') AS [Anything_Outstanding?]," & _ " sum(c_grossmargin) / 2 AS [Gross_Margin]" & _ " FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_COMMISSIONS AS COM" & _ " Left Join ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.dbo.AT_ACS_PROJECTOUTSTANDING AS OUT" & _ " ON COM.det_costheader = OUT.project" & _ " WHERE c_broker = ''HKGCGOJT''" & _ " GROUP BY det_costheader, c_broker, cuname, ch_name, ch_date_req, outstanding'" & _ " FROM sys.databases d" & _ " where name like '%AccountsLive'" & _ " FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)" & _ " .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 11, '');" & _ " exec( @Sql );"`